# Nginx to Apache reroute for PHP

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I'm trying to use both Nginx and Apache concurrently, and have the need to use PHP to execute a contact script.

I have set `Apache` to listen on `port 8080`, while `Nginx` is listening on `port 80`.

My first attempt was to do this within the config of Nginx:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

However when I attempted to execute the script online, it produced the following:

http://puu.sh/aCy05/d072e3052d.png

How do I configure Nginx so that it redirects the request through Apache (running PHP) and executes the script?

Comment: If you access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/send.php` directly from the browser, does it work?

Comment: Look carefully at the error : It is generated by Apache. So nginx is correctly forwarding the query, but either Apache is misconfigurated or the script send.php indeed does not exist.

Comment: I think after testing your query it's a misconfiguration of Apache, you have any ideas off the top of your head?

Comment: I've made sure it does indeed exist, however Apache cannot find it for some reason.

Comment: I think you need to configure your apache root path